# Check if substring exists in Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML document which has a keyword attribute

```
<Books>

    <Book name="Steve Jobs" type="biography" keywords="biography technology apple">

        <Authors>

            <Author>
...
```

I want to find all "Books" with the keyword "biography". I haven't been able to find a method to search within a string. How would one approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One can use this XPath 1.0 expression and this could be more efficient than performing a tokenization**:

```
/*/Book[contains(concat(' ', @keywords, ' '), ' biography ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following XQuery returns all Book elements which do have 'biography' in the set of keywords, separated by whitespaces (the sequence is built by tokenize, the separator are whitespaces)

```
doc('yourdoc')//Book['biography' = tokenize(@keywords, '\s')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use:

1. //Book[contains(@keywords, 'biography')] -- or
2. //Book[starts-with(@keywords, 'biography')]